# Angular ng-pick-datetime - Disable the input based on a condition

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I'm working on **Angular 8** and I'm using **ng-pick-datetime** plugin. I wish to disable the date time picker as well as the input element that triggers it based on a condition dynamically. I tried to search but couldn't find any solution. Following is my code:-

```
<input type="text" 
 style="cursor: pointer; border: none; height: 25px; text-align: center; font-size: small; box- 
 shadow: 0 0 0 0 white !important;"
 placeholder="DD MMM YYYY" class="datepicker" 
 id="date" [disabled]="!editable" #date 
 [owlDateTimeTrigger]="date" [owlDateTime]="date" 
 [min]="min" [max]="max"> 

<img alt="" 
  src="./assets/images/datepicker.svg" 
  style="position: relative; top: 6px; margin-right: 5px;" height="20px" width="20px;">


<owl-date-time [disabled]="!editable" [pickerType]="'calendar'" 
  #date></owl-date-time>
```

When tried above, a class termed **owl-dt-trigger-disabled** gets attached to my input element. It seems like the input element is disabled, but we can still edit the input element manually.

[image]

Here, when my **'editable'** variable is false, I want to disable the datepicker input. If anyone have an answer, please help me.

I found a question but didn't find any answer-
[Can't dynamically disabled ng-pick-datetime component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421072/cant-dynamically-disabled-ng-pick-datetime-component)

**Update**

Please find the stackblitz link for the same question asked above. I have already set **editable** as false -
[Angular ng-pick-datetime - Disable the input based on a condition](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-pick-datetime?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: can we get the whole code or stackblitz link for the same?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the answer. You just need to add an attribute **[readonly]="true"** to your input. That will make it select only the date and so you cannot edit it.

```
<input [readonly]="true" type="text"
 placeholder="DD MMM YYYY"
 id="date" [disabled]="!editable"
 [owlDateTimeTrigger]="date" [owlDateTime]="date"
 [min]="min" [max]="max">
```

I have edited my stackblitz. Please check the answer.

Comment: readonly not working, it will open calender and editable.
code - `<input [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt3" [readonly]="data.disable" [disabled]="data.disable" formControlName="endDate" class="txtquestion"                             [owlDateTime]="dt3">`

Comment: Did you check what is in your `data.disable`? Either way, you don't want your textbox to be maually editable. So, directly set `[readonly]="true"`.

Comment: `data.disable` is `true` from API

Comment: I guess we are both talking about 2 different things. Using `[readonly]="true"`, the calendar will open. My issue was that I was able to type any text inside the textbox (please refer my posted image). If you don't want to open the calendar, you need to try this - `<owl-date-time [disabled]="data.disable" [pickerType]="'calendar'" 
  #date></owl-date-time>`. Add `[disabled]="data.disable"` in the owl-date-time tag.

Answer (score 1):

To disable `ng-pick-datetime` in Angular (ng-version="6.1.10"), add 'readonly' & 'disabled' attribute in input field, and the same time add 'disabled' attribute in `owl-date-time`.

```
<input [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt3" formControlName="endDate" class="txtquestion date-field"
[owlDateTime]="dt3" [readonly]="data.disable" [disabled]="data.disable">

<owl-date-time [pickerType]="'calendar'" [disabled]="data.disable" #dt3></owl-date-time>
```

Reference - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime